# Could not import environment config in an ember controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Here are the ember libraries that I used:

```
ember-cli  : 0.1.7
Ember      : 1.8.1
Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.12
Handlebars : 1.3.0
```

My config/environment.js file contains some api keys. According to the link (http://www.ember-cli.com/#Environments) I can access the variables from environment file with the paths ../config/environment or your-application-name/config/environment.

Now, I need a url from the environment file in a controller and I have the following code:

```
import Ember from "ember";
import BaseController from 'appkit/controllers/base-controller';
import config from '../config/environment';

var NavigationController = BaseController.extend({
    homeUrl: config.URL
});
export default NavigationController;
```

When checking the browser I have the following error:

```
Error: Could not find module appkit/controllers/config/environment
```

I changed the import path from the controller with 'appkit/config/environment' (according with the above link) and I get the same error message. The problem is that the config/environment.js file is not in the appkit/controllers folder but on the same level with the appkit folder.

My question is: what is the path for importing the config/environment from a controller?

Answer (score 5):

According to the guide: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/configuring-ember/configuring-your-app/

> You can access these environment variables in your application code by importing from your-application-name/config/environment.

Answer (score 2):

The key is that the error notes that it is looking for the `config` directory in `appkit/controllers/` which is one directory too deep. Due to how your `NavigationController` is presumably nested, you'll need an import statement like this:

`import config from '../../config/environment';`

Comment: I already tried to change the path into ../../config/environment, ../../../config/environment and appkit/../config/environment (where appkit is my appname) and the same error is displayed with the corresponding path. For example, for the appkit/../config/environment I get the following error message:Error: Could not find module appkit/../config/environment

Comment: where in your project is `NavigationController`?

Comment: NavigationController is in proj_folder\app\controllers\navigation\index.js and the config is in proj_folder\config\environment.js.

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot find a solution to use variables from the configuration file, I moved the configuration variables in a json object in the index.html file that is generated from my .NET application and I solved the problem.